# Getting parsed data from website with \frac and \sqrt how would i replace these with what they are in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, parsing, replace

I am getting strings from a website regarding mathematical equations, when there is a fraction the string it return is '\frac{number1}{number2}'

What I want to do is replace the \frac{}{} and make it for example from '\frac{1}{2}' to '(1)/(2)'

I assumed that re.groups would help with this and tried

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '\\frac{1}{2}'
>>> print(s)
\frac{1}{2}

>>> m = re.match(r'\frac{(\w+)}{(\w+)}',s)
>>> m.groups()
('1', '2')

>>> f = s.replace('\\frac{{}}{{}}'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2)), '{}{}{}{}{}'.format('(', m.group(1), ')/(', m.group(2), ')'))
>>> print(f)
\frac{1}{2}
```

I still get \frac{1}{2}

Am I going about this all wrong? Or is there an easier way to do this, or did I make a mistake? I cannot figure it out whatsoever

Also sometimes there is more than one in a string such as

'\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3} + 3\frac{1}{3}'

Just trying to replace those parts of the string with a more readable version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's leverage the `re.sub` function, which will replace all matches in the string.

For the `\frac` case, let's use the following as are regex pattern:

```
patt = r'\\frac\{(\w+)\}\{(\w+)\}'
```

We have to escape the leading `\` in front of `frac`, and `{` and `}` are metacharacters, so we escape those, too.

So we can now just do `parsed_s = re.sub(patt, r'(\1)/(\2)', s)` where `s` is the source string.  This will replace all of the matches in the string with the desired format.

Comment: Now how exactly would you deal with muiltiple \frac statements in a string with different numbers? I got your solution to work using

parsed_s = re.sub(patt, r'({})/({})'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2)), s)

with the groups function, but that replaces all occurences doesn't it?

Comment: ```In [2]: patt = r'\\frac\{(\w+)\}\{(\w+)\}'

In [3]: patt
Out[3]: '\\\\frac\\{(\\w+)\\}\\{(\\w+)\\}'

In [4]: s = r'\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{j}'

In [5]: s = r'\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}'

In [6]: re.sub(patt, r'(\1)/(\2)', s)
Out[6]: '(1)/(2) + (3)/(4)'
```

Comment: Trying to paste code above, sorry.  So, with the solution I proposed in the parent, `\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}` yields `(1)/(2) + (3)/(4)`, which is the desired output, no?  The `\1` and `\2` refer to the first and second capture groups, which will be whatever numbers are matched.

Comment: Alright yea, then this is the solution! Thanks man, I appreciate it exactly what I needed to figure out. Do you mind clarifying what's going on in the comment above? Kinda hard to read

Comment: The above was just me running the `\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}` example through ipython.